# Proving that a function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

I am asked to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is discontinuous on the set $A$= {$\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}$ } but also continuous on the complement of $A$.

This is what I proposed: 
$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if $x\in A$}\\ 
0 &\text{if $x\notin A$} \\
\end{cases}$.

Now, I am trying to prove this is continuous on $A^c$, but I am not sure what to take for my $\delta$. In this case would taking $\delta=\epsilon$ be okay? In this case we would have $c\notin A$.

So, Given $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta = \epsilon$.

Suppose $|x-c|<\delta$.

Then, $|x-c|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x= 0$, then yes, $\delta = \epsilon$ would work. This is because if $|x| < \delta$, then $|f(x)| \leq |x| < \delta = \epsilon$ ($|f(x)| \leq |x|$ follows from the fact that $f(x) =0$ or $f(x)=x$ for all $x$).

In the other cases, I don't think it works. Let $x \neq 0 \in A^c$. Then, $f(x) = 0$. So we would like $|y-x| < \epsilon$ to imply that $|f(y)| < \epsilon$. However, this would not be true. For example, if $x = .99$ and $\epsilon = 0.5$, we would be tempted to think that if $|y-x| < 0.5$  then $|f(y)| < .5$. However, the above is violated with $y = 1$.

So, the $\delta$ to take in such a case would be the following : for all such $x$, there is a ball of some fixed radius around $x$, which does not intersect $a$. Let $\delta$ be the radius of this ball, then this $\delta$ works for all $\epsilon$. It is therefore dependent on $x$, but not on $\epsilon$.

EDIT : Should mention, your candidate is the correct answer i.e. this function is continuous on $A^c$ and discontinuous on $A$. The only question is as to the relation between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ now, but the edit is merely for completeness.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me for the case when $x=0$ to pick $\delta=epsilon$. However, I do not get what you mean we can pick for the case if is not zero?

Comment: Do you at least understand why $\delta = \epsilon$ does not work if $x \neq 0$?

Comment: Yes, I do because then we would have an issue at $0$.

Comment: The set $A$ is a set of points in the plane, but it is what we would call discrete : each point in $A$ is at least some positive distance away from all other points in $A$. Can you draw $A$ and see why this is true? If yes, I will continue to explain.

Comment: Well, I do not know how to draw on here, but on my paper I drew a graph. I have that there are jumps at 1/2, 1/3, and so on.

Comment: So it jumps from 0 and each value in $A$.

Comment: Yes,  that is fine. Now, for any point outside $A$, *except zero*, can you draw a small enough ball so that it avoids intersecting $A$? Note that the radius of this ball would depend on the point you choose. If I write mathematically, it may not be convincing enough, hence I request you to verify this  for yourself. Pick any points e.g. pick $x = \frac 23$, $x = 2$, $x  = \frac 2{9}$ etc.

Comment: Okay, so I want to find a delta small enough so I avoid the points in $A$?

Comment: Precisely. You can find this $\delta$ for all points outside $A$, *except zero*. That is why $0$ has to be handled somewhat specially, as compared to the other points.

Comment: Oh, right! okay, then I see why would need to consider the case of 0 separately. Okay, then I should consider the case when $c\neq 0$ and find a delta?

Comment: Yes, you can mathematically find such a $\delta$. I would recommend it as an exercise to you, but again, the other answer has actually done it for you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, how would we find this delta? We want that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ right? But here, when c is not 0, still we have f(c) is 0.

Comment: Would it be enough in this case just to show continuity at 0?

Comment: Continuity at zero would clearly not be enough to show. As for the first comment, $\delta$ depends on the point, do not think of it as "the" $\delta$. For example, if $x = \frac 23$, $\delta$ would be any positive number,such that the interval of radius $\delta$ around $x$ will not intersect $A$. Clearly $\delta = \frac 14$ would work,and so would anything smaller,$\delta = \frac 17$, for example. So $\delta$ very much depends on $x$. The thing is, can we write $\delta$ as a function of $x$? This is done in the other answer, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Okay, I did not know what you were referring to before. Then we need two cases, when c<0 and c>1?

Comment: Some $c$ would lie in between $0$ and $1$ as well. For example, $c = \frac 23$ and $c = \frac 37$ and so on. These are the numbers between  $0$ and $1$ that are not in $A$. The answer above has considered these  : he wrote : "for $x \in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac 1n)$, take $\delta = ...$".

Comment: I see,  I am just trying to grasp at the cases being shown. Just as an aside, to show discontinuity for $A$, can we say take $x_1\in A$ then $f(x_1)=x$ but lim f(x)= 0 as x approaches $x_1$, so there is discontinuity?

Comment: Yes, this is enough.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will work on making sure I understand the other part. I just was wondering, I posted a question previous to this and in a comment I placed a suggested answer, but I am not sure it is correct. Would you mind just seeing that my choice of delta works?

Comment: Definitely. Please add a link to the question. Also, I request you to upvote this answer if you found it useful(or downvote if unuseful), because I have found our conversation fruitful, so have upvoted the question.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517250/determining-discontinuity-on-a-set this is the link. My answer is in the comments below.

Comment: I was thinking could we do something here along the lines of take $x_0\notin A$, then $f(x_0)=0$ and lim f(x)= 0 so we have continuity?

Comment: I had a look at your other answer, and I will be honest I could not spend much time on it.  I am sorry for the same.

Comment: It is okay, I figured it out eventually!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x_{0}>1$, take $\delta<\min\{\epsilon,x_{0}-1\}$. For $x_{0}\in(1/(n+1),1/n)$, take $\delta<\min\{\epsilon,1/n-x_{0},x_{0}-1/(n+1)\}$.

For $x_{0}<0$, take $\delta<\min\{\epsilon,|x_{0}|\}$. For $x_{0}=0$, we can take $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: Why did you consider the cases when x>1 and x<0? What about the points in between?

Comment: Of course, because the domain of the function is ${\bf{R}}$ and you want to consider the complement of $A$.

Comment: Hmm, then this is how you picked the restrictions for x?

Comment: Not quite sure what you were asking but I just want to do it case by case because the $\delta$ cannot be taken throughout the same.

Comment: I see, but wouldn't is be okay to just look at the fact that $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: Clearly not,right? $f(x)$ may indeed be continuous at zero, but it is no way clear that this must imply continuity everywhere else in general.

Comment: True, okay, I am just having difficulty understanding the choice of delta when the points are between 0 and 1.

Comment: Could we do another argument not using delta and epsilon to avoid all the cases that arise? Maybe by sequences of considers just $x_0\notin A$ so $f(x_0)=0$ and lim f(x)=0 so we have continuity?